# How to put a space between values on an axis label

Tags: r, ggplot2, spaces, superscript

I want to add the following axis label to a plot:
Ba:Ca (µmol mol -1)
At the moment I have managed to get the -1 into a superscript, which is what I am after, but I am not able to get the space in after mol and before the -1. Do I need to add something to the script below as it just prints it as mol-1?

```
ggplot(aes(Distance3, newBa)) + labs(y= expression (paste('Ba:Ca (µmol mol'^ -1,')'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can get a space with `~`:

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = expression(paste('Ba:Ca (µmol mol'^~-1,')')))

# or without paste:
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, wt)) + 
  geom_point() +
  labs(y = expression(Ba:Ca~(mu*mol~mol^~-1)))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you I did it!....I'm on an R high :-)